# Wie nennt man eine Person, mit der man häufiger mal Sex (eine Romanze) hat?

Tags: single-word-request

Gesucht ist quasi das Gegenstück zu fester Freundin/festem Freund in einer Beziehung.

Was sagt man, wenn man (auch in ihrem Beisein) gefragt wird:

> „Ist das deine Freundin?“
>
> — „Naja, äh, nee, nicht so ganz ... wir sind, äh, ... vielleicht *friends with benefits*?“

Aber eigentlich trifft es das nicht ganz, wenn man eben nicht richtig Freundschaft, sondern eine Art Beziehung hat ... nur eben mit „lieb haben“ statt „lieben“. Und deutsch ist es ja auch nicht.

Danke für Eure Antworten! Ich bin gespannt.

Comment: Do you want to be my "it's complicated" on facebook?

Comment: Ich weiß eigentlich nicht genau, was du meinst, wenn es weder eine feste Freundin, noch friends with benefits, noch eine Affäre ist.

Comment: OK, dann ist es halt halt *friends with benefits* – und nach über 40 Jahren sexueller Freizügigkeit in Deutschland gibt es noch kein deutsches Wort dafür? (und ich find's auch auf Facebook schade, dass es keinen Eintrag dafür gibt ... denn es ist überhaupt nicht kompliziert :))

Comment: Nein gibt es tatsächlich nicht. Liebhaber/-in ist sicher die eleganteste Lösung (weil es z.B. auch einen mitwissenden festen Partner zulässt), aber in jugendlichen Kreisen am häufigsten gehört habe ich tatsächlich das grässliche "fuck buddy". :/ Deutsch ist wirklich eine sehr arme Sprache, wenn es um Sex geht. "Friends with benefits" finde ich übrigens schrecklich, das klingt irgendwie nach finanziellem Vorteil. Schöne Frage übrigens, so ein Wort suche ich auch grad. ^^

Comment: @ladybug: Ich hörte analog dazu auch schon den Begriff `Fickfreund/-in`. Eleganter als das englische Wort ist das jetzt aber auch nicht.

Comment: @0x6d64: natürlich ist das nicht eleganter, ist ja auch nur ne fast wörtliche Übersetzung (wörtlich wäre wohl "Fickkumpel", aber mit dem Doppel-K klingt das wohl zu komisch... wobei ich eher vermuten würden, dass viele Schiss hätten, für schwul gehalten zu werden)

Comment: Bei *The Big Bang Theory* wurde es mit "Freunde mit Sonderleistungen" übersetzt.

Comment: Ich kenne die *de facto* wortwörtliche Übersetzung *Freund/in mit Vorzügen*.

Comment: Vater u. Mutter?

Comment: Wenn mensch es zu Freunden sagt, würde es wohl warscheinlich auf "... wir vögeln nur" oder "... wir schlafen nur miteinander" enden lassen.

Comment: Could you please post a word in your mother tongue which conveys your meaning very well? And I never want to be the one who is called "nur eine Fickfreundin". :( :( As a matter of fact there is no reason to let others know you are just f***ing someone. Gentleman genießt und schweigt

Comment: "Sidebitch" wäre da so ein begriff aus dem Englischen, wenn auch nicht ganz salonfähig.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update**

Wenn beide Menschen nicht in einer festen Beziehung mit einer dritten Person sind, so könnte **Lover** der geeignete Begriff sein.

> "Ist das dein neuer Freund?" - "Nein, wir sind bloß Lover."

Eventuell könnte auch der Begriff *Liebhaber(in)* passen.

---

*Antwort auf erste Version des Titels mit ("Affäre")*

Auf Deutsch nennt man eine solche Person eine **Geliebte** oder einen **Geliebten**.

> "Hast du gehört?" – "Nein, was?" – "Herbert soll eine Geliebte haben." –  "Nein, echt?!? Das hätte ich ihm nie zugetraut."

Dein Beispiel ist vielleicht etwas ungewöhnlich, da diese Liebschaften selten öffentlich preisgegeben werden.

Man verwendet auch manchmal folgende Begriffe für die Beziehung der beiden:

- Seitensprung
- Affäre
- Verhältnis
- Liaison
- Beziehung
- Liebschaft
- Abenteuer

> Sie hat eine Beziehung mit dem besten Freund ihres Mannes.
>   Florian hatte eine außereheliche Affäre mit seiner Chefin.

Comment: Das klingt alles ganz vernünftig, aber auch nicht ganz passend: In unverheirateten Kreisen ist es heutzutage ja üblich, trotzdem Sexpartner/innen zu haben, und wenn man nunmal länger eine hat, kriegt die Umwelt das ohnehin mit, schließlich wird man zusammen gesehen, ist auch im Freundeskreis häufig Arm in Arm/Hand in Hand unterwegs usw. Dein Beispielt ist korrekt für verheiratete Menschen, die mglw. ihren eigenen Ehepartner nicht mehr lieben und daher jemand suchen, den sie lieber haben. Ich meinte aber grade eine Beziehung ohne Liebe, "Geliebte" wäre daher komisch.

Comment: Und als Begriff kannst du vielleicht "Romanze" noch aufführen ...

Comment: Das Wort "Affäre" im Titel hat bei mir die Assoziation ausgelöst, dass hier einer der beiden in einer festen Beziehung mit einer dritten Person ist.

Comment: In meinem Bekanntenkreis heißt sowas immer Affäre ... aber ich ändere das dann mal ...

Comment: Liebhaberin ist sehr schön – es ist deutsch, klingt positiv und nicht zu fest. Das werde ich dann wohl nehmen.

Comment: @Felix: "Gespielin" (w) - männliche Version fehlt; "G'spusi" - geschlechtsneutral. War sehr lange zurück nicht "Buhle" das betreffende Wort (bis es qua Kirche negativ und dann unmöglich geworden war). Vielleict könnte man "Lustfreund/in" erfinden?

Comment: Ist "wir sind Lovers" ein Tippfehler oder sagt man das in Südtirol tatsächlich so? Wo ich herkomme, wurde *Lover* so weit eingedeutscht, daß der Plural *die Lover* lautet, und nicht *die Lovers*. (Genauso wie bei *die Raver*, *die Killer*, *die Banker*, *die Driver*.)

Comment: @RegDwight Da Südtirol ein katholisches Land ist, wird das Wort praktisch nicht verwendet. :-P Scherz beiseite - Habe selbst gezögert, ob ich das Plural-S setzten soll. Denke auch, dass du Recht hast.

Comment: 'Gespielin' oder 'Betthupferl' scheint mir nicht völlig unmöglich, aber meist drückt man sich davor so konkret zu werden - was als Kosewort im 2er-Verhältnis noch durchgeht wirkt bei weiteren Zuhörern schnell abwertend. 'Affäre, Liason, Beziehung, Liebschaft' auch benutzt werden, wenn man nicht verheiratet ist.

Comment: Ich finde es furchtbar, einen englischen Modebegriff als erste Wahl anzubieten. Es gibt genügend deutsche Begriffe dafür.

Answer (score 12):

**Gspusi**

Leider funktioniert das nur in Bayern und Österreich; im Hochdeutschen fehlt tatsächlich ein nicht-abwertender Begriff für diesen Sachverhalt. **Bettgeschichte** würde mir noch einfallen, da liegt aber schon eine Abwertung drin. Ich habe auch schon erlebt, dass Menschen in dieser Situation "Das ist meine **Affäre**" gesagt haben, aber mein Sprachgefühl meint, dass das eigentlich nicht geht.

Comment: Gspusi passt definitiv.

Comment: Gspusi wird aber nur südlich des Weißwurstäquators verstanden.

Comment: OK, das G-Wort kommt definitiv nicht in Frage (ich bin Berliner ;)), klingt aber süß. "Das ist meine Affäre" würde bei mir noch als akzeptabel durchgehen, ich finds aber eigentlich unschön und möchte es nicht selbst verwenden.

Comment: Hmh, jetzt weiß ich wieder, warum ich immer nach Berlin wollte. ^^

Answer (score 6):

Eine(n) "Friends with benefits' zu haben wird in Deutsch auch "Freundschaft Plus" genannt.

[Dr. Sommer](http://www.bravo.de/dr-sommer/freundschaft-plus-darf-es-auch-etwas-mehr-sein-358132.html) aus der BRAVO schreibt:

> Freundschaft Plus wird eine Freundschaft genannt, in der beide miteinander schlafen, ohne ein Paar zu sein.

Ein typischer Dialog wäre:

> A: Ist das deine neue Freundin?
>
> B: Nein, wir haben eher eine
> Freundschaft Plus.

Comment: Ich hab ja schon viele Varianten gehört, *Freundschaft Plus* aber noch nicht.

Comment: Hätte ich nicht verstanden.

Answer (score 2):

Wie wärs mit dem Ausdruck (reine) Bettbeziehung?

Answer (score 1):

[Gespielin](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gespielin) wurde ja schon im Kommentar von Gottfried Helms als Option erwähnt, allerdings nennt der Duden dazu tatsächlich ein männliches Gegenstück [Gespiele](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gespiele_Spielkamerad_Gefaehrte) (was ich persönlich allerdings noch nie gehört habe).

Ansonsten funktioniert je nach Kontext evtl. auch *Mätresse*.

Comment: **hüstel** Stecher **hust, hust**

Comment: Beides aber eher Begriffe, die eher historisch klingen. So würde glaub ich kaum jemand sagen.

Comment: @glglgl Das kommt u.a. davon wenn man mit _Hui Buh_-Kassetten aufwächst. `Itzo`, `ehedem`, `einstmals`, `dereinstens` ... mindestens eine davon in jeder der 23 Folgen, und vermutlich noch einige mehr die mir grad' nicht einfallen. Muss ich wohl dringend mal wieder auffrischen ;-)

Comment: Downvote ... interessant. Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

Ich folge meist den Verbableitungen und Substantivierungen, um mir über die Bedeutung von Worten klar zu werden:

Eine *Beziehung* ist es, wenn man sich auf einander bezieht. Räumt man einander dabei vor jedem Anderen Vorrang ein, heißt es *Ehe* - mit oder ohne Trauschein.
Nebenbei: Das Wort "Trauschein" trägt im Namen, worum es bei der Sache eigentlich geht: Vertrauen - man traut einander. Oder Mut: man traut sich was.
Die Ehe (mit Trauschein) ist aus juristischer Sicht ein Wirtschaftsvertrag, der Gemeinschaft, Gefährtenschaft, Partnerschaft und gegenseitige Verantwortung beinhaltet.

Wer zusammen lebt, hat *Gesellschaft*. Wer miteinander lebt, bildet eine *Gemeinschaft* und hat *Gefährten*. Verwirklicht man dabei gemeinsame Projekte, dann ist es eine *Partnerschaft*.

Ein Mensch mit dem man gemeinsam Dinge unternimmt, ist ein *Kumpel*. Wenn man sich eben nur - oder hauptsächlich - zum Sex verabredet, passt *Fickfreund* oder, für mich passender, *fuck buddy*.

Wenn man bei einem Menschen kein Blatt vor den Mund nehmen muss, ist das ein *Freund* - oder ein Speichellecker.

Wenn man einander liebt: *Liebhaber* und *Geliebte* haben eine *Liebschaft*. Ein Wort dass anscheinend total außer Mode gekommen ist, aber auch einen eher kurzfristigen Beigeschmack hat.
Die *Affaire* ist dem Wort nach "quelque chose à faire", etwas zu tun. Wenn man mal drüber nachdenkt: etwas, um der Langeweile zu entfliehen.

*Liebe* wird für mein Empfinden mit zu vielen dieser anderen "Modelle" gleichgesetzt. Liebe ist für mich, wenn man sich freut, dass es einem anderen gut geht - nicht mehr und nicht weniger.

Ist einer in den anderen *ver*liebt, dann wird es kompliziert - und das nicht unbedingt für denjenigen, der verliebt ist.

Der Sex dient beim einen wie beim anderen entweder zur Entspannung
oder er ist das Tüpfelchen auf dem i.

Answer (score -2):

Früher war das schlicht *eine Bekannte*.

Comment: *Früher* möglicherweise. Heute ist meinem Gefühl nach eine Bekannte jemand, mit dem man gerade *nicht* schläft und ein Ersatzbegriff für Freund/Freundin (weil Freund missverständlich sein kann).
Was hat man früher jemanden bezeichnet, den man nur kennt oder befreundet ist? Ggf. hat sich ja die Bedeutung von zwei Wörtern getauscht, das wäre interessant.

Comment: @0x6d64 Auch als Bekannte, natürlich. Es kommt eben manchmal darauf an, *wie* man etwas sagt.

Comment: Ingo hat insofern recht, als man dafür kein besonderes Wort braucht. Entweder man spricht mit Außenstehenden, dann geht es sie einen Dreck an, ob man miteinander schläft, oder man brüstet sich damit, dann legt man wohl wenig Wert auf die Unverfänglichkeit des Ausdrucks!